# Powering sewing machine card

Tags: power-supply, voltage-measurement, repair, testing

[image]

Hi, I received an electronic card to repair. The user says that it doesn't work and didn't say anything more, such as why it was broken or which part is not working.

So I want to plug in an energy source to the board to check capacitor's voltages, or if is there too much warming parts on board. But I dont have any experience on this kind of board, this is the first time that I get a sewing machine's electronic board.

[image]

this question is for general situations.

If I want to give energy to an electronic board, how should I do successfully? There is a 250V 6.3A fuse, and there are fuse varistors which are 220V rated. Also there is a GND point on board (first image) left up, at the side of varistor and a +33V point just below the fuse. There are lots of clues. How can I give energy to this board, reading correctly thoses clues?

Comment: What device is this? This question is too generic.

Comment: Can't you see how was this board installed in the original equipment?

Comment: What is your job and why did you receive this circuit board? Who sent it to you and what is the relationship between you and the sender? Did you or the company that you work for supply him the circuit card? If so, who did you buy it from and why not ask them for this information if it's your job to fix it? If it is your job then why don't you have schematics?

Comment: you also have not provided any information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you asked for general situation advice, I will offer some general recommendations.

1. If your first impulse on troubleshooting an unknown board is "let's just apply power and see what happens", I think you should reconsider your approach. You don't know what the appropriate input actually is, what the expected outputs are, or if there is any sequencing or fail-safe circuitry needed to make the board *do* anything. I would start by first asking more questions from the person who supplied the board:

- Which product did this board come from? (Manufacturer, model number, etc.)
- Have them provide a picture of any labels on the device for clues about input requirements (voltage, frequency, etc.)
- Ask them to describe the fault in more detail.

2. Contact the manufacturer and ask if they have any schematics or repair resources available. Alternately, scour the Internet and see if you can find this from any third-party sources.
3. Continue your reverse-engineering activities to understand the basic flow and sequencing of the circuit. Draw your own block diagram. Identify test points (which you have already done) and voltage rails (based on capacitor ratings and ICs connected to those rails)
4. Conduct a visual inspection of the board for components which look damaged; probe and measure before applying power.
5. Try powering DC rails by connecting a current-limited DC source to the rail. Slowly walk the voltage up and watch the current meter, gently relax the current limit and bring the rail up to the expected voltage if it is possible to do so.
6. Once you are confident that the DC rails are OK, identify which parts of the board are primary (mains-connected) so that you will not incidentally contact or probe any dangerous areas. I would use a small variac with a conservative fuse rating (equal or lower than the fuse in the product) and walk the AC voltage up slowly to see if any on-board power supplies are operating correctly. (I didn't see any transformers on this board so it's possible the entire assembly is mains-connected.)

It is quite likely that without the complete sewing machine, it will be impossible to diagnose everything fully so there may be some back-and-forth with this particular customer if they are unable or unwilling to send the machine.

Answer (score 0):

You really need the entire sewing machine. It's likely that this board is supplied from a transformer that is still in the machine.

The first step should be to check for obvious failures such as a blown fuse or visible damage to the board (e.g. burnt out component). If everything looks OK the general approach is to follow the voltages from input to output, so in this case you would plug the sewing machine in to the mains and check the AC voltages coming out of the transformer. If the supply to the board looks OK you can check for other voltages on the board. Large decoupling capacitors are often a good starting point.

If the power supplies look OK then you really need to understand how the board works before you can check anything else.

Comment: This board seems to be complicated. I counted 16 different connectors (for data, sensors, power, whatever), with about 100 different connection pins.